# Customize datatable column for laravel application

Tags: datatables

First of all, I'm just a beginner in this field. I'm facing a problem where I would like to align each column based on the requirement. I'm only able to customize the header of the datatables. When it comes to styling the column of the table, I havent found any solution that suits with my current application.
Any help guys?

I have tried to use doc.styles.columnDef, but it seems this method will hide my current table pagination and the search function.

The actual code, btw, been implemented by previous developer before.

```
<script>
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
        "paging": true,
                 "fixedHeader": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "scrollX": false,
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "{{ trans('general.lengthMenu') }}",
            "zeroRecords": "{{ trans('general.zeroRecords') }}",
            "info": "{{ trans('general.info') }}",
            "infoEmpty": "{{ trans('general.infoEmpty') }}",
            "search": "{{ trans('general.search') }}",
            "infoFiltered": "{{ trans('general.infoFiltered') }}",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "{{ trans('general.first') }}",
                "last": "{{ trans('general.last') }}",
                "next": "{{ trans('general.next') }}",
                "previous": "{{ trans('general.previous') }}"
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                {"orderable": false, "targets": 0}
            ]
        },
        responsive: true,
    });


     var reportTitle = 'Invoice Listing Report';
     var table = $('#data-table').DataTable();

     var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
         buttons: [
            {
                extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                orientation: 'potrait',
                titleAttr: 'PDF',
                customize: function(doc) {

                    doc.content.splice(0, 1, {
                      text: [{
                        text: reportTitle+'\n\n',
                        bold: true,
                        fontSize: 16
                      }],
                      margin: [0, 0, 0, 12],
                      alignment: 'center'
                    });


                    // Style table header
                    doc.styles.tableHeader = {
                        bold: !0,
                        fontSize: 11,
                        color: 'black',
                        fillColor: '#FFF',
                        alignment: 'center'
                    };
                                        //Style table column here?



                    var objLayout = {};
                    objLayout['hLineWidth'] = function(i) { return .5; };
                    objLayout['vLineWidth'] = function(i) { return .5; };
                    objLayout['hLineColor'] = function(i) { return '#aaa'; };
                    objLayout['vLineColor'] = function(i) { return '#aaa'; };
                    objLayout['paddingLeft'] = function(i) { return 4; };
                    objLayout['paddingRight'] = function(i) { return 4; };
                    doc.content[1].layout = objLayout;
                  }
            }
        ]
    }).container().appendTo($('#buttons'));

</script>
```

Any helps on how to customize each column of the table? Sorry for bad english